# How to use credential injection on Apache Zeppelin with python interpreter

Tags: python, credentials, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to retrieve the credentials for a database on Apache Zeppelin while using python as the interpreter, but I haven't found any examples on how to do that.

I've created my credential entity here:

[image: zeppelin_cred]

Also enabled credential injection on the python interpreter as follows:

[image: zeppelin_interpreter]

And here's the silly notebook code I'm using to try and recover the credentials created above:

```
%python

username = {mysqluser.user}

print(username)
```

I've also tried using them in the connection string as well:

```
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format('{mysqluser.user}', '{mysqluser.password}', 
                                                      database_ip, database_name))
```

Does anyone know what the correct syntax for this would be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your are just missing the parantheses. It should read

```
username = '{mysqluser.user}'
```